# Partial sum of series $\,\cos^2(nx)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Help me please to find partial sum of this sequence.

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cos^2(nx)
$

$\left(\dfrac{e^{ixk}+e^{-ixk}}2\right)^2=\cos^2(kx)$

I tried to apply the same approach, like $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin(nx)=\operatorname{Im}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{inx}\right)\,.$

Then used sum of geometrical progression

$1+t+t^2+\ldots+t^{n-1}=\dfrac{1-t^{n}}{1-t}\,.$

But I think this method will not work here.
Here I’m stuck.

Comment: Render $\cos^2(nx)=(1/2)[1+\cos(2nx)]$ and sum each of the latter two terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\;x=k\pi\;$ for some $\;k\in\mathbb Z\;,\;$ then

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N\cos^2(nx)=\sum_{n=1}^N\cos^2(nk\pi)=\sum_{n=1}^N\left[(-1)^{nk}\right]^2=\sum_{n=1}^N1=N\,.$

If $\;x\ne k\pi\;$ for any $\;k\in\mathbb Z\;,\;$ then

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N\cos^2(nx)=$
$\quad=\displaystyle\dfrac12\sum_{n=1}^N\big[1+\cos(2nx)\big]=\dfrac 12\left[N+\sum_{n=1}^N\dfrac{\sin x\cos(2nx)}{\sin x}\right]=$

$\quad=\displaystyle\dfrac 12\left[N+\dfrac12\sum_{n=1}^N\dfrac{\sin\big((2n+1)x\big)-\sin\big((2n-1)x\big)}{\sin x}\right]=$

$\quad=\displaystyle\dfrac N2+\dfrac1{4\sin x}\sum_{n=1}^N\bigg[\sin\big((2n+1)x\big)-\sin\big((2n-1)x\big)\bigg]=$

$\quad=\displaystyle\dfrac N2+\dfrac1{4\sin x}\bigg[\sin\big((2N+1)x\big)-\sin x\bigg]=$

$\quad=\displaystyle\dfrac N2+\dfrac{\sin\big((2N+1)x\big)-\sin x}{4\sin x}=$

$\quad=\displaystyle\dfrac N2-\dfrac14+\dfrac{\sin\big((2N+1)x\big)}{4\sin x}\;.$